# What does "x == 01" mean?

Tags: java, conditional-statements, equality

I am reviewing code written by someone who is not presently available and I came across this:

```
double x = ...;
if(x == 01) {
    // do something
}
```

I have never seen this before.  Does it have a special meaning?

Comment: Are you specifically referring to `==` or `01`?

Comment: Or, with the assignment provided, perhaps the equality between a double and int?

Comment: This shouldn't be closed (unless it's a duplicate). It's a valid question.

Comment: Sorry the question wasn't clear.  I was reviewing someone else's code.  I marked the response that applied to my intended question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`01` (a number starting with 0) represents an **octal** (base 8) number in Java.

Answer (score 4):

1. `01` means `1` in octal (which is also 1 in decimal, so there is no difference in this case. For more octal information, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal.)
2. If you are asking why a new variable `x` was created, it could be used later in the code.
3. (I highly doubt this) If you are asking what `==` means, it means "is equal to." Just 1 `=` is an assignment, as you see in the first line.

Answer (score 0):

It has a special meaning in a sense that it is an octal number notation. Otherwise it is useless and confusing. 01 is int constant 1. It should be

```
if(x == 1) {
    // do something
}
```

there's no difference for javac. It will be compiled into the same bytecode. Besides, javac will convert your expression into

```
if(x == 1.0D) {
    // do something
}
```

If you decompile .class you will see it. This automatic conversion from "lesser" to "greater" type is called type promotion.